# How to check if a process is closed/alive?

Tags: c++, winapi, time, process

I am writing a program in C++. In my code I run the process *A* using the function [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The process *A* starts another process *B*. *B* works for some time and then closes. The runtime of *B* depends on various parameters. Sometimes *B* works for 1 hour but sometimes -- nearly for 2 hours. I need to know when *B* ended its work (when *B* is closed). How can I check for the close of the second program *B*? In other words, is there any function (for example, in WINAPI) to check if the process is alive?

Comment: Off-topic: When speaking of processes, a better word for "closing" would be "termination": Application windows close; processes terminate.

Comment: Thank you for the note, I have forgotten the word "termination".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`WaitForSingleObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), passing in the process handle.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I would like to clarify.
So let `hProcessB` be a handle of process _B_. Can I do the following?

`if (WaitForSingleObject (hProcessB, INFINITE) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
{
 // Then my process B terminated and hence I do something...
}`

Comment: I am doing this in order to make sure that the process _B_ terminated. I put the flag `INFINITE` to not specify a concrete period of time (the time-out interval) but wait for the process _B_ termination. I knew it from MSDN.

Comment: @Vladimir, yes. Note you could also pass in a timeout to `WaitForSingleObject()` if you want to periodically check but would need to check for `WAIT_TIMEOUT` also.

Comment: Ah, so this is a timeout for the periodic check whether the process is still running. Looks like I did not read the documentation properly enough. Thank you very much for the information. Now I will try to apply it all in practice.

Comment: @Vladimir: You can even use `if (WaitForSingleObject (hProcessB, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)`, which will return instantly in either case.

Comment: @MSalters But what would be the difference between `0` and `INFINITE` in this case?

Comment: @hmjd @MSalters I wrote in my program like this:
`... while (WaitForSingleObject (hProcessB, INFINITE)! = WAIT_OBJECT_0); ...`
That is when the process _B_ is running, we execute the operation `;`. When it terminated, we go further. Is that correct?

Comment: @Vladimir: No, when B is running, you don't execute anything at all. You don't even get a slice of CPU time. (This may be a good thing). With a zero timeout, as I proposed, you wouldn't give up the CPU at all. You would just test is B is still running, and depending on the answer can do two different things. If this isn't clear enough, ask a new question about the appropriate timeout, and state what you want to do if process B is or isn't running.

Comment: @MSalters, I got it. I do not need the immediate return of `WaitForSingleObject()`. I want to stop on the call of this function and "stay there" until the process _B_ is terminated. Let it be a kind of blocking function: everything is blocked until _B_ is running. In my program, I am waiting for _B_ termination to make further actions. I do not know how to explain this understandably. Sorry if my explanation is unclear.

Comment: But, anyway, my program provides now correct results. I am performing some mathematical calculations and making log files. So the files are okay.